# Data Factory - String manipulation, data after the last comma

Tags: string, azure-data-factory

I have a column of data I'm manipulating in a Derived Column activity.

Data is numerical and separated by commas. I need the right hand most number from each row.

The required output number is sometimes three, four or five characters in length

Example rows of input data

0.0

1.2, 3.45, 67.89

12.3, 4.56

This would be the required output:

0.0

67.89

4.56

An additional example of how my source data looks in ADF.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3BJ7.png

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your data might already be a complex type, so you could try:
salaries_hourlySalary[size(salaries_hourlySalary)]

If the data is a string, you could try this expression:
split(text, ',')[size(split(text, ','))]